# Bind this in nested literal object

Tags: javascript, this, bind, object-literal

Let's say I have this code

```
(function() {

    function Foo(arg) {
        this.name = arg;
    }

    Foo.prototype = {
        bar: {
            baz: function() {
                alert(this.name); // Undefined...
            }
        }
    }

    var foo = function(arg) {
        return new Foo(arg);
    };


    window.foo = foo;

    return foo;
}());

foo("Anything").bar.baz();
```

How can I make "this" in my function "baz" refers to the object Foo without using bind or apply when I call it from outside ?

Comment: `this` is set by how a function is called.  So, unless you replace this by using something like `.bind()` it is set by how it's called and since `baz` is method of `bar`, when you call `baz` as `bar.baz()`, `this` will be `bar`.  Generally, nesting methods that are all meant to operate on the same parent object like this is way more trouble than it's worth because you have to constantly reset `this`.  You can hack it to work, but it is not how the language was designed to work.

Comment: Can gou explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @jfriend00 I know that in this exemple it refers to 'bar' and that 'this' always depends of how a function is called. But I wanted with this structure to access the 'name' attribute.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  It's not a natural Javascript design pattern.  You can force it using various hacks, but it is not the way JS was meant to be written.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I would strongly recommend **not** building nested structures like that, or at least not on the prototype, because the `bar` object is **shared** amongst all of the instances, which opens the door to a *lot* of cross-talk-style bugs. Instead, I'd create `bar` within the constructor.

> How can I make "this" in my function "baz" refers to the object Foo without using bind or apply when I call it from outside ?

You may have `bind` and `apply`/`call` slightly confused. You wouldn't use `bind` when *calling* the function, but when creating it. Unless you use `bind` (or something equivalent to it), you can't do what you've said you want, because absent `bind` (or similar), `this` is set by how the function is called, and so `this.bar.baz()` will make `this` be `this.bar` within the call.

Here's how you'd build `bar` within the constructor, and use `bind` to make `baz` use the correct `this`:

```
function Foo(arg) {
    this.name = arg;
    this.bar = {
        baz: function() {
            alert(this.name);
        }.bind(this)            // <== Note
    };
}
```

Example:

```js
function Foo(arg) {
  this.name = arg;
  this.bar = {
    baz: function() {
      snippet.log(this.name);
    }.bind(this)            // <== Note
  };
}

var f1 = new Foo("f1");
var f2 = new Foo("f2");
f1.bar.baz(); // "f1"
f2.bar.baz(); // "f2"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

More about cross-talk: The naive thing to do is to just add one line to your `Foo` constructor, and keep `bar` on the prototype:

```
this.bar.baz = this.bar.baz.bind(this);
```

**That would be a very bad idea**, because you'd get cross-talk between instances:

```js
function Foo(arg) {
  this.name = arg;
  this.bar.baz = this.bar.baz.bind(this); // DON'T DO THIS
}

Foo.prototype = {
  bar: {
    baz: function() {
      snippet.log(this.name);
    }
  }
};

var f1 = new Foo("f1");
var f2 = new Foo("f2");
f2.bar.baz(); // "f1" -- cross talk! Should be f2
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I willingly used `prototype` for the reasons you mentioned so is there a way of doing it with that structure ?

Comment: @user3292788: No, you can't have one single `bar` object shared amongst instances with one single `baz` property referring to a function that uses different `this` values without using `apply` or `call`. This feels a **lot** like the X/Y problem: You want to do X, you've come up with Y (the `bar/baz` thing) as how to do X, and are asking how to do Y. I suggest posting a new question asking how to do X (share information between instances or whatever). This is not how you'd want to do that. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use bind at declaration time to properly scope this, e.g.

```
function foo() {}.bind(this);
```

Comment: OP is looking for a way without using bind or apply as stated in the question

Comment: @PatrickEvans: The OP said *"...without using bind or apply when I call it from outside..."* which suggests to me that they aren't *quite* clear on what `bind` does.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to help OP.